# How to find all numbers between 1 and N that are not divisible by 2, 3 and 5

Tags: python

I want to print all integers between 1 and `sk` which aren't divisible by 2, 3, 5.

Tried to make a list, and I think it worked, but showed me that 10 *(example for sk definition)* is divisible by all integers from 1 to 10.

```
sk = int(input("Enter number: "))
z = 1
x = range(1, sk + 1)
while z == sk:
    if (sk % x) == 0:
        if x is x % 2 != 0 or x % 3 != 0 or x % 5 != 0:
            print(sk, "is divisible by", z)
            z = z + 1
        else:
            print(sk, "is not divisible by", z)
            z = z + 1
```

Why is it giving the wrong output?

Comment: If you enter a number other than 1, then `z == sk` is never true, and the while loop is never entered at all.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich That's only the first of many problems...

Comment: There are SO MANY problems with your code that make this question very broad..

Comment: Rewrite your code and use `for value in range(1, sk + 1):` as the loop.

Comment: What is so bad about this question that it deserves 9 downvotes? There is a clear goal, the issue with the current code is explained, the code is included..

Comment: I think everybody hates beginners.

Comment: Actually, first 7 votes were casted when question's readibility wasn't so good. Other ones are probably just bandwagoners but of course that doesn't justify number of downvotes this one gets when there are reaaaallly crappy questions out there getting upvotes.

Comment: Sorry, but my main language isn't english...

Comment: @Marius that's fine. I edited it for you. If you feel that it's different from what you meant, you can always change it back

Comment: Thank you for editing almost everything in this question :D I think now everyone will understand what I meant because you edited it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

1. Your while loop never executes because `z` is 1 and `sk` is 10, so they are not equal.
2. `sk % x`. `x` is a range object, you don't want to use the modulus on that.
3. `if x is x % 2 != 0` this bit is wrong. You probably want to remove the `x is`
4. You don't need `z`, if you loop over the range object you already have the numbers from 1 to 10. Then you can also remove the nested if.

Here is a simplified version of your code that works, using a for loop as someone suggested in the comments.

```
sk = int(input("Enter number: "))
for x in range(1, sk + 1):
    if (sk % x) == 0:
        print(sk, "is divisible by", x)
    else:
        print(sk, "is not divisible by", x)
```

Gives

```
Enter number: 10
(10, 'is divisible by', 1)
(10, 'is divisible by', 2)
(10, 'is not divisible by', 3)
(10, 'is not divisible by', 4)
(10, 'is divisible by', 5)
(10, 'is not divisible by', 6)
(10, 'is not divisible by', 7)
(10, 'is not divisible by', 8)
(10, 'is not divisible by', 9)
(10, 'is divisible by', 10)
```

All you have to do is loop over the range 1 to `sk`, and check if `sk` is divisible by that number by doing `if (sk % x) == 0:`

---

Edit: actually that code doesn't check if the number is divisible by 2 3 or 5. Here is a snippet that does

```
sk = int(input("Enter number: "))
for x in range(1, sk + 1):
    if x % 2 == 0 or x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0:
        print(x, "is divisible by 2 3 or 5")
    else:
        print(x, "is not divisible by 2 3 or 5")
```

So instead of checking `if (sk % x) == 0`, we now check `if x % 2 == 0 or x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0`

The output is now

```
Enter number: 10
(1, 'is not divisible by 2 3 or 5')
(2, 'is divisible by 2 3 or 5')
(3, 'is divisible by 2 3 or 5')
(4, 'is divisible by 2 3 or 5')
(5, 'is divisible by 2 3 or 5')
(6, 'is divisible by 2 3 or 5')
(7, 'is not divisible by 2 3 or 5')
(8, 'is divisible by 2 3 or 5')
(9, 'is divisible by 2 3 or 5')
(10, 'is divisible by 2 3 or 5')
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand what what wrong. Now code is perfectly working.

Comment: @Marius I actually made a mistake because it doesn't check if it's divisible by 2 3 or 5, I'll make an edit soon

Comment: If what, this is what I expect from output: *1 is not divisible by 2, 3, 5* //new line// *2 is not divisible by 3, 5* So first number is range and the end of checking divisibility has to be 2 or 3 or 5 or 2, 3 etc.

Comment: @Marius yes, it does that now :)

Comment: Actually you made a mistake in your edit. `z = 1` is not needed

Comment: @Marius yes, my bad. Accidentally copied that line

Comment: But what I need to do if I need to change position from `print(x, "is divisible by 2 3 or 5")` to `print(x, "is not divisible by 2 3 or 5")` ? `if x % 2 != 0 or x % 3 != 0 or x % 5 != 0:` not working.

Comment: @Marius you need to use `and` then: `if x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 != 0 and x % 5 != 0:`

Comment: Suggestion: `if x % 2 == 0 or x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0:` ---> `if any(x%i == 0 for i in [2, 3, 5]):`.

Comment: @KevinGuan yeah I tried to keep it simple for our friend here :p

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Yeah, but that would be more Pythonic ;)

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Thank you.